# CAS single sign out not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, single-sign-on, servlet-filters, cas

I have installed a CAS server (v3.5.2) on Apache Tomcat and 2 clients on JBOSS.
Everything works fine unless single sign out.

I think all I made is fine but there is still this problem.

My configuration server-side :
In WEB-INF\deployerConfigContext.xml :

```
<bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService">
    <property name="id" value="1" />
    <property name="name" value="HTTP and IMAP on localhost:8080/firstCasClient" />
    <property name="description" value="Allows HTTP(S) and IMAP(S) protocols on localhost:8080/firstCasClient" />
    <property name="serviceId" value="^(https?|imaps?)://([A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.)*localhost:8080/firstCasClient/*" />
    <property name="ssoEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="enabled" value="true" />
    <property name="evaluationOrder" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService">
    <property name="id" value="2" />
    <property name="name" value="HTTP and IMAP on localhost:8080/secondCasClient" />
    <property name="description" value="Allows HTTP(S) and IMAP(S) protocols on localhost:8080/secondCasClient" />
    <property name="serviceId" value="^(https?|imaps?)://([A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.)*localhost:8080/secondCasClient/*" />
    <property name="ssoEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="enabled" value="true" />
    <property name="evaluationOrder" value="1" />
</bean>
```

Configuration in clients :
In web.xml :

```
<!-- CAS SINGLE SIGN OUT -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
    <!-- because of use of Saml11TicketValidationFilter -->
        <param-name>artifactParameterName</param-name>
        <param-value>SAMLart</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- other filters -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8888/cas-server-webapp-3.5.2/login</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>service</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080/firstCasClient</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8888/cas-server-webapp-3.5.2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>service</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080/firstCasClient</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

I hope someone would find what is wrong
thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Make sure in your argumentExtractorsConfiguration.xml file that the casArgumentExtractor bean has the disableSingleSignOut property set to false. If you see the following:

```
<bean id="casArgumentExtractor"
      class="org.jasig.cas.web.support.CasArgumentExtractor"
      p:httpClient-ref="noRedirectHttpClient"  
      p:disableSingleSignOut="${slo.callbacks.disabled:false}" />
```

Take a look in your cas.properties and make sure slo.callbacks.disabled is not set to true. the `${slo.callbacks.disabled:false}` means look for that property, and if it is not found default it to false.